# Angular 6 component, apply css to class applied with hostbinding?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-components, angular2-hostbinding

I normally use a global SCSS file in my apps, but today I wanted to make some scss scoped to just my component.

I have set a class on the component via `@HostBinding` (of `class.card`).

I can style items *inside* my component, such as the `caard-body`, but how can I apply overrides to this component's `card` class?

In other words, I have several cards on the page.  I have styles that I only want to apply to this card, to make it look different. So I'd like to apply css such as

```
.card { background-color: violet; }
```

So that only this card is violet. I want to make this css part of this component, so everywhere I use it it will automatically be a violet card. (In reality I want to more than a simple thing, but you get the idea)

My component TS:

```
import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reviews',
  templateUrl: './reviews.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reviews.component.scss']
})
export class ReviewsComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.card')
  true;

  @Input()
  review;

  constructor() {}
}
```

My Component SCSS:

```
.card-header {
  border: 0;
  color: #cf0989;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.card-body {
   ...
}
```

My component HTML:

```
<div class="card-header">Testimonials</div>
<div class="card-body">

  <div class="review-image">
    <img class="rounded-circle"
        alt="{{review.acf.article_author.post_title}}"
        src="{{review.acf.article_author.acf.image}}">
  </div>

  <div class="review-content">
    <p class="review">
      <span [innerHTML]="review.content.rendered"></span>
    </p>
    <p class="reviewer-name">{{review.acf.article_author.post_title}}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

The selectors in my CSS for `.card-body` and `.card-header` work fine, but I cannot style this `.card`.  Adding this, for example does nothing:

```
.card { background-color: violet: }
```

How can I create SCSS selectors in the component's SCSS file that also apply to the class applied to the component via `@HostBinding`?  Can I?  Should I?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I need to use `:host`, is that correct?

```
:host {
  &.card {
    padding: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do that but as it's generally speaking not always best practice and should be avoided if possible. If the styles you want to apply is part of the concern of this component itself, I would suggest you add a wrapper tag for your template. `<div class="card">your card header and body tags</div>`. Then you can style it normally without any tricks or workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new answer here to add a bit more.

Yep the answer is to use `:host`. As [@Xinan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915401/xinan) pointed out using `:host` by itself isn't considered best practice (if view encapsulation is turned off for the component, the selector will no longer match anything).

The solution to this is to combine it with an existing selector - in this case the class you've "HostBound" to your component. Like this (basically your answer but on one line):

```css
.card:host {
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

In fact with this approach we can simplify a little more, remove the `@HostBinding` and simply use `:host` with the component's selector like so:

```css
app-reviews:host {
    padding: 2rem;
}
```